# CTS error faced

Tags: android-cts

In android CTS 8.1 code there is no `CtsDeviceAdmin.apk`

When I am re-running the failed & not executed modules using retry command then the cts test report shows only previously passed modules result i.e result not updated?

How much time takes to run cts on android 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

Running all the CTS suite varies from build to build you have to run it completely once to have a sure estimate. If retrying is stuck, and sometimes is getting stuck at the same result for multiple runs.you can make a sub-plan with the test that weren't run and execute that.

```
add subplan --name cts_remain2 --result-type not_executed --session 10
run cts --subplan cts_remain2
```